# randomForest error this function only works for objects of class `(rfsrc, grow)' or '(rfsrc, forest)'

Tags: r, error-handling, random-forest

I am trying to generate a partial dependance plot from my tree classification model. I am using randomForest model and I am getting an error message. Would someone point me in the right direction?

"Error in partial(rf.model, pred.var = top_five_predictors[4], plot = FALSE,  :
this function only works for objects of class `(rfsrc, grow)' or '(rfsrc, forest)'

Here is an extract of my code:

````
top_five_predictors = c("annualised_mileage", "mth_since_last_serv", "age_of_vehicle_years", "num_serv_dealer_purchased", "sched_serv_warr")

#Construct the 5 plots
library(pdp)

# Annualised Mileage
p1 <- partial(rf.model, pred.var = top_five_predictors[1], plot = FALSE, rug = TRUE, plot.engine = "ggplot2")```
````

Comment: The error tells you that `rf.model` is the wrong type of object to be passed to the `partial` function. You haven't shown us what `rf.model` is or how it was created, so it's not clear how we can help you here.

Comment: Thanks, I had restarted r and loaded the libraries again and it started working